# Override Matblazor style

Tags: css, styles, blazor, matblazor

I am using matblazor for a web project and I need to override some styles.
For example, I have a button and I need the text to be aligned to left. The property is not read by Matblazor but using Blazor without the material library is possible to do that.

How can I override this property?

Comment: Post the code that you have. In this case, the structure of your files is important as well so please use an IDE like Codesandbox for this: https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: @m4n0 https://codesandbox.io/s/matblazor-textfield-issue-fj070?file=/ButtonObject.razor if you have any doubts about the code please ask me! Thank you

Comment: I don't see any output: https://nimb.ws/20jV83

Comment: Sorry, but it's a confidential project and so I cannot provide the entire code. But I can share with you an image: the right image is my output, the left one is what I'd like to obtain (but with Material Style). The code posted is how I'm trying to achieve the goal.

https://ibb.co/P1CPdB0